# Angular 1.3, required, form.$invalid, and saved passwords

Tags: angularjs

I have a login form that has a username and password. Both are required to trigger other form elements.

However, in chrome if the password is saved, `form.$invalid` returns true and the digest doesn't re-run when the saved information gets added. Is there any way to require fields being saved and set by the browser and have angular re-check `form.$valid`?

Comment: See bug and workaround in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, I was facing a similar problem some time back. The trick is to get the browser to fire input events for things that may have been filled in by chrome autofill (but haven't updated).

If you have a submit or click handler for the form submission, you can trigger the input event on all your inputs so that angular will pick up the changes by autofill.

You may do something like this

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.run(function() {
// Trigger input event on change to fix auto-complete
$('input, select').on('change',function() { $(this).trigger('input'); });
});
```

to fire input event on all inputs.

Here's the original [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1072) related to your problem.

Comment: What's the alternative w/o using jquery? I tried substituting the `trigger` with `triggerHandler` but that didn't work.